# Ubuntu 16.04 on my Lenovo doesn't see my network card, neither Wifi/ethernet connections

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, lenovo

I've bought a lenovo thinkpad t470p and I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 but I cannot connect to internet. It seems that Ubuntu doesn't recognize the network card.

[image: network card missing]

[image: results from the terminal]

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/894323/edit) the question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

Comment: sure, I do it right now :)

Comment: If you installed 16.04.2 it would work right away.

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.